# Best way to build pages, or page equivalent

Tags: theming, 6

I manage a Drupal 6 site that has various content types and is set up to display them in various methods, all of which work just fine.

However, marketing likes to generate specific campaign based landing pages.  These are primarily static pages, and historically have had no usability extras at all.

Using drupal, the design team has started to request a higher level of interaction, different blocks depending on role, use of the customers name if we have it... little things for the most part.

The solution I'm seeking:

...ideally lets the designers to be able to do this themselves.  Dropping in the html and images, css, video, whatever.

...is potentially free of the site theme... this is trickier.  I'd like them to be able to not include the header and footer if they didn't want it... or use a different body background.

...doesn't require a large number of modules.  I stated this in a way that confused people before... we use a lot of modules.  I don't mind modules.  But I'd to find a solution that isn't a kludge of 8 modules mashed together in a way that isn't exactly what they were designed for and doesn't deliver exactly what you want.

Or as mtro put it as concise and eloquent as possible: designers regularly give me html/img/css packs that need to live on a single page within the site, and you want to streamline creating those pages without recurring template work?

My question is what do other What do other Drupalers do when you have non-standardized content that is regularly added and has partial or no theming?

Comment: In my opinion, this question is too vague. If the question would be on one specific area it has more chances to get answered

Comment: Are you saying something like this.. designers regularly give you html/img/css packs that need to live on a single page site, and you want to streamline creating that page without much template work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I would build a Custom Page Template. This is ideal for landing pages and it essentially creates almost like a subtheme in your existing theme with just one file. It also allows you to do a plain vanilla layout however you want without headers, sidebars, footers or whatever but still leveraging the power of Drupal 6 and CCK (hopefully you are using that module).

I wrote a blog post on how to do this: http://highrockmedia.com/blog/creating-custom-content-type-page-templates-drupal-php

Comment: Ultimately this is the solution I went with... my designer actually sent me the blog post.  Was able to set it up and have it working in less time than it would have taken to upload one raw page... and because my designers have access, I won't have to touch it any more than that... win all the way around.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) and [CSS Injector](http://drupal.org/project/css_injector).

Panels does most of what you are looking for; it presents a user interface for laying out varied content on a page without having to dig into HTML. It's not quite a pure WYSIWYG interface (theme styling might not apply to the Panels UI depending on your set-up), but it is as close as you can get with an out-of-the-box solution in Drupal.

CSS Injector will allow your designers to write CSS specifically for one Panels configuration through the UI, without having to touch the theme files.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  My concern here is the complexity... Go build a layout, then build a custom content panel in another screen, then a custom style on another page... it seems excessive for each page that is going to be unique.  This is what I started doing before I asked the question.  This turns out to be a lot more work if I get a package from a designer because I then have to cut out all the pieces from their document and put them into the different entry forms... OR... I'm doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: I hadn't actually tried used Panels since I was much n00bier, while they aren't the solution I want to use here. I do have places I will use them.  Thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect to be able to create completely unique and custom pages within your Drupal site without having to do a lot of work. If each unique marketing page uses a different layout, you're going to have to create a different layout, no matter what solution you are using. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you want, but as far as out-of-the-box solutions within the Drupal CMS, Panels is as close as you're going to get to the "magic" you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Nope... that was the answer I expected... I just thought "this is used for businesses... someone has probably had to deal with this" I just wanted to see if they had found a better way than harder-than-just-coding-it-raw which apparently they haven't. Sigh. Maybe I'll write one.

Comment: I understand that sentiment, but a lot of people really do enjoy working with Panels and it has a lot of neat features although the UI is a bit clunky. If you do want to contribute to finding a better solution for this sort of situation, I would strongly suggest working to help improve Panels rather than trying to build something from scratch. That's the open source way :)

Comment: Of course... I don't play well with others... but I'm not keen on reinventing the wheel either...

Answer (score 0):

I see Drupal as a CMS (content management system) and not a super themers product.  If the marketing pages have a short lifetime, and the content is not reused elsewhere, then I see nothing wrong with doing a static page called by a redirect.  That way, marketing does all there design work (woo) and all you have to do is point the redirect in the right direction, add some images to the directory and maybe put a wrapper around everything to insure their css is applied correctly. It is probable that doing complex things could take multiple modules, but the effort is worth it if you need the flexibility.  In this case you may not.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  Doing the loads manually just ads more work to my plate, and a slower turnaround for my customers... its a CMS... seems like there ought to be a way to use the system to manage content.

Answer (score 0):

sheena_d has the right idea here. If you want each individual node to be a completely different layout for these sorts of situations, you should check out panelizer. It allows you to, per content type, specify if the nodes therein can be panelized. If they can be, you can setup default panel output for them and override it after the node's been created to provide completely different layouts and blocks etc. It's a really great module that Merlinofchaos also built, it builds upon the knowledge you gain using page_manager and panels already, and provides a lot more flexibility than you've had up until this point.

I can't suggest it enough and I think it will solve your problem perfectly.